# Array parameter, select all when the parameter is empty

Tags: google-bigquery

### Context

I am working with Google BigQuery and Django to make parameterized endpoints that will return data from the database.

I am working with an array as parameter using `ArrayQueryParameter()` to filter the data based on multiple job titles.

### The problem

Currently I am filtering the data like this:

```
# Query
...
WHERE jobtitle in UNNEST(@jobtitle_param)
```

```
# param and building the query

jobtitle_param = self.request.query_params.get('jobs').split(',') if self.request.query_params.get('jobs') else ["%"]

...

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    query_parameters=[
        bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("jobtitle_param", "STRING", jobtitle_param),
    ]
)
```

When the job title parameter is not passed to the endpoint I want to return data for all job titles  like the `%` does in:

```
WHERE something LIKE "%"
```

What is the best way to return data for all job titles when the parameter `jobs` is not passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this problem by changing the query from:

```
...
WHERE jobtitle in UNNEST(@jobtitle_param)
```

To:

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM UNNEST(@jobtitle_param) AS jobs
    WHERE jobtitle LIKE jobs
```

And set the default value of the parameter to the wildcard `%` like this:

```
jobtitle_param = self.request.query_params.get('jobs').split(',') if self.request.query_params.get('jobs') else "%".split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the show, but the way I solved this was by creating a condition that evaluated to `True` if the list of parameters was empty, specifically `ARRAY_LENGTH(@my_array) = 0`. In your case, the result would be

```
...
WHERE (jobtitle in UNNEST(@jobtitle_param) OR ARRAY_LENGTH(@jobtitle_param) = 0)
```

Comment: this is where I was at, but bigquery has trouble setting empty arrays as param.
at least in Golang